# Toggle element visibility with jQuery!

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="header">Text</div>
<div class="hiddenArea">sdsada</div>

<div class="header">Text2</div>
<div class="hiddenArea">sdsada</div>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$('.header').click(function() {
        var t = $(this).next('.hiddenArea').slideToggle();
    });
```

When the hiddenArea is revealed I want to hide the other hiddenArea if it is visible?
I want to make this so that I can add other headers and hiddenAreas if I need them.

#### Update:

Thanks Guys, ended up doing this:

```
$('#messages .header').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $('.hiddenArea').slideToggle();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have one hiddenArea visible when the form is rendered this will work.
Also note you dont need the filter inside the next method as next only ever gives you the next sibling.

```
$('.header').click(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ( ! $el.next().is('visible') ){
       $('div.hiddenArea:visible').slideUp( function(){
           var t = $el.next().slideDown();
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: this works great redsquare thanks, but both hiddenAreas are not visible initially!?

Comment: it only needs one to be visible initially!

Comment: when you click on the header where the next hiddenArea is already visible, the hiddenArea is hidden then revealed, not very slick, i was hoping to do nothing if the appropriate hiddenArea was already visible

Comment: thats a late breaking change to requirements!! will edit the above

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys, ended up doing this:

```
$('#messages .header').click(function() {
        if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
            $('.hiddenArea').slideToggle();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I never trust any of the toggle's as they can get out of synch with quick double clicks etc. Anyway cool you got it sorted